# How to create date object in C++?

Tags: c++, c++-chrono

What is the proper way to create Date object in C++?
I want C++ analogy of this python code:

```
import datetime

x = datetime.date(2020, 5, 17)
delta = datetime.timedelta(days=1)
x = x + delta
```

I was reading about chrono and found only time_point https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/time_point

but I don't see constructor like this `date(year=2020, month=1, day=2)`

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/year_month_day

Comment: @n.m. I wonder why it doesn't have `operator+` for adding days (only years and months).

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I wonder why it has these operators at all. They make little sense to me. What is January 31 2023 plus one month? What is February 29 2020 plus one year? I would expect people to work in terms of chrono::sys_days (or local_days) and convert to and from y.m.d only when user-friendly representation is needed.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat:  The main reason is efficiency, and the ease with which the programmer can switch to an efficient data structure for day arithmetic.  More detailed information is here: https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date/wiki/FAQ#day_arithmetic

Comment: @n.m.  Each calendrical type has a member function `ok()`. Clients can call that to discover if there is a valid calendrical value in types such as `year_month_day`. This library adds months and years to a `year_month_day` and completely ignores the day field, which can result in something that answers `!ok()`. One can then decide how to handle it:  Roll over into the next month? Snap to the end of the month? Throw an exception? Ignore? Other libraries choose for you. This library lets you choose. More details here: https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date/wiki/Examples-and-Recipes#not_ok_is_ok

Comment: @HowardHinnant it is not immediately obvious that these operations can result in invalid date, so the principle of least surprise is violated. Why not just do the addition manually? It is not hard and the result is obvious.

Comment: You certainly can do year and month arithmetic manually if you choose to.  But if omitted, clients would clamor for them.  And 50% would expect snap-to-end-of-month and 50% would expect roll over into next month.  And many expect `x + months{y} - months{y} == x`.  One way to think of this library is as a collection of low-level date algorithms for doing dates however you want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A [date object](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/year_month_day) is available in the standard library since c++20.

```cpp
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>


int main ()
{
    std::chrono::year_month_day date(
        std::chrono::year(2023), 
        std::chrono::month(5), 
        std::chrono::day(7));

    std::cout << "Year: " << static_cast<int>(date.year())
              << ", Month: " << static_cast<unsigned>(date.month())
              << ", Day: " << static_cast<unsigned>(date.day()) << '\n';
}
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e979eac28b6879cf)

Even though stream output should exist it is not available in the demo environment above, hence the manual cast of each value prior to output.

Arithmetic operations like the one you mention are provided either as:

- [member functions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/year_month_day/operator_arith) (e.g. `date += months`)
- [non member functions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/year_month_day/operator_arith_2) (e.g. `date1 + months`)

Note that the `year(), month(), day()` methods return object that are **not** the same as the corresponding specializations for [duration](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/duration) (`std::chrono::years`, `std::chrono::months`, `std::chrono::days`) but merely integral representation of the count of such quantities (hence the static cast to `int` is ok). That said, you can perform [arithmetic operations](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/509d2f143e817935) with the corresponding durations.

Answer (score 10):

chrono doesn't add calendrical support until C++20, and the various implementations are still working on that.  Microsoft VC++ is solidly out front and currently shipping the full spec.  Otherwise you can use my [free, open source library](https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date) with C++11/14/17 which implements the new chrono calendrical support, except it is in namespace date.  I'll describe C++20, just know that if that isn't available to you, there's a workaround for that.

C++20 has two (or more) date types.  These are the main two:

- `sys_days`
- `year_month_day`

`sys_days` is a `chrono::time_point` based on `system_clock`, but with a precision of `days`.  It is actually a type alias for:

```
time_point<system_clock, days>
```

All this type does is hold an integral count of days after 1970-01-01 (or before for negative values).  This makes it very efficient at day-oriented arithmetic.  It is also good at converting to a date-time type, which is just any `system_clock`-based-`time_point` with a precision finer than `days`, such as `system_clock::time_point` (typically microseconds to nanoseconds precision).

`year_month_day` is a `{year, month, day}` data structure.  It is very good at year and month arithmetic.  And it has very efficient access to the year, month and day fields.

One can implicitly convert between `sys_days` and `year_month_day`, in either direction, with no information loss.

```
year_month_day ymd = ...;  // some date
sys_days       sd = ymd;   // the same date in a different data structure
ymd = sd;                  // round trip - no change in value
```

One can easily create a `year_month_day` with "conventional syntax", for example:

```
auto ymd = 2020y/5/17;
```

`ymd` has type `year_month_day`, with the year 2020, the month 5 (or May), and the day 17.  The `y` suffix on 2020 denotes a value of `year`, and the '/' operators assume the next two integers represent month and day in that order.

Two other orders are permissible:  `month/day/year` and `day/month/year`.  As long as the first field is strongly typed, the following two fields can be either strongly typed, or just int.

```
auto ymd2 = May/17/2020;  // ymd2 == ymd
auto ymd3 = 17d/5/2020;   // ymd3 == ymd
```

Your example code can be written:

```
sys_days x = 2020y/5/17;
x += days{1};
```

- The conventional syntax creates a `year_month_day` which implicitly converts to `sys_days`.
- One day is added to the value creating a `sys_days` equal to 2020y/5/18.

Other date types in C++20 include:

- `local_days` : good for keeping the difference between the date local to a time zone, as opposed to UTC.
- `year_month_weekday` : good for specifying dates such as the third Sunday of May 2020 (`Sunday[3]/May/2020`).

One can inter-convert among the various date types, for example:

```
year_month_day ymd4{Sunday[3]/May/2020};  // ymd4 == ymd
```